# Importing secure code in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am little unclear on the ‘secure sever code’ section of the meteor guide as to how code remains secure and accessible. I understand that you can place code in a server directory and call it from a place where code it shared, but how does this work with imports?

Won't you need to import the secure function into the shared code location so it works on the server. Yet, that secure code is not available on the client, as expected, so will create an error. Is there some sort of conditional import you have to set up (depending on whether the code is run on the server or client) to make this work?

Could someone let me know where my understanding on this topic is lacking?

Many thanks.

Comment: You invoke the server code using Meteor method calls from the client to the server. If you want to have a "method stub" that runs on the client for "optimistic" updates you can use create a separate version for the client, that only depends on what the client knows. Whatever code you don't want on the client, don't import it from the client's entry point.

Comment: You can't directly call code in server directory from code in common directory. You can only do that using `Meteor.call` as @MasterAM wrote, but that's an RPC, and doesn't require additional imports.

Comment: Thanks both, that makes sense. I was just a little confused from the security guide where they are calling secure code like this: MMR.updateWithSecretAlgorithm(this.userId);